# How to link to a named chunk of documentation in Haddock?

Tags: haskell, haddock

I might be missing something really obvious (or might have developed temporary blindness staring at the Haddock user guide), but I can't seem to find any way to link to a [named chunk of documentation in Haddocks](http://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#named-chunks-of-documentation)

*Edit:* I'm trying to create an internal hyperlink from one part of the doc to another named chunk of documentation. I've tried the following:

```
-- You may want to take a look at 'findByPkHelpers' section for
-- variations of this function.
--
-- I even tried putting '$findByPkHelpers' but didn't work
--
-- ... snip ...

-- ** Some heading
-- 
-- $findByPkHelpers
```

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working? Is putting `-- $somechunkname` in the export list not enough?

Comment: Have added clarifications to the question.

Comment: Can you give a full reprodicible example?

Comment: Oh, and named chunks are not for linking. AFAIK a reference to a named chunk is simply replaced by the contents of the named chunk.

Comment: For linking you can try anchors: http://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#anchors

Comment: Hang on, are anchors and named-chunks completely different concepts? I've spent an hour trying to link to a named chunk using the `#something` syntax, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda: Yeah, anchors and named chunks are unrelated.

Comment: @sjakobi there isn't any reason why **both** of these should exist, right? It should be possible to link directly to named chunks of documentation, right?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda: In my understanding, named chunks are about reducing clutter in export lists. So they do have a different purpose than anchors. You should still be able to make a link to a named chunk by including an anchor label in the named chunk.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the syntax `#myanchor` to create an anchor, and then you can link to it with `[my link text](#myanchor)`.  For example, in my export list I have

```hs
    -- | #launchaprocess#

    -- * Launch a process
    , runProcess
    , readProcess
```

and then in the body of the file I have a link to this anchor

```hs
-- | Once you have a @ProcessConfig@ you can launch a process from it
-- using the functions in the section [Launch a process](#launchaprocess).
```

(N.B. in the case of anchors next to section headers in export lists there *must* be a blank link between them otherwise the `*` introducing the header will be interpreted as a Haddock-comment bulleted list!)

[Thanks to @sjakobi for pointing out this functionality]